# How to use variable that contains a dollar sign($) in .env?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, .env

I tried to use a variable in `.env` like this example:

`REACT_APP_STATION_API=https://station.tw/api/Metro?&\$format=JSON&\$spatialFilter=nearby(StationPosition,{lat},{lon},{radius})`

however, it comes out to be :
`'https://station.tw/api/Metro?&=JSON&=nearby(StationPosition,{lat},{lon},{radius})'`

how to keep my dollar sign($) in .env with React? (CRA)

I want this:
`'https://station.tw/api/Metro?&$format=JSON&$spatialFilter=nearby(StationPosition,{lat},{lon},{radius})'`

And I'm confused at the differnce between `.env.development` and `.env`.

When I deleted `.env` and the App used `.env.development` with totally the same content, the variable came out to be the one I wanted!
`'https://station.tw/api/Metro?&$format=JSON&$spatialFilter=nearby(StationPosition,{lat},{lon},{radius})'`

I don't know what mistake I made. Please help me!

Comment: Did you try wrapping the value part (in your case the URL) in your .env file with single quotes? As far as I know everything in a .env file should be treated as a string but I seems in some situations a table is not a table ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have run a sample code using your key `REACT_APP_STATION_API` u specified in ur `.env` in my code for testing. However it comes to be exactly same as written in `.env` file(in my PC).

Here's my output:-
[image]

As far as I know `.env.development` file can se used in development phase as the file name suggest and the code can accept any one `.env` file contents at a time, so u must specify/place any one `.env` file in your project. I hope this helps!